# Token mismatch error when uploading some files

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I implemented a form for uploading 3 different files.

Here's one :

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('register_update' , Auth::user()->id) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}" />
    <div class="file-container">
       <input type="file" name="carte-id" id="id-file" class="input-file">
       <div class="fake-input-file">
         <div class="cross-container" id="cross-cont1">
           <i class="icon-plus-symbol" id="cross1"></i>
         </div>
         <div class="file-label" id="id-label">
           <label>Carte d'identité</label>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
```

Here is the function in my Controller:

```
public function registerUpdate(CardAvsRequest $request){
        $id = Auth::user()->id;
        $first_name = User::find($id)->student->first_name;
        $last_name = User::find($id)->student->last_name;
        $name = $first_name . " " . $last_name;
        $message = "";
        if ($request->hasFile('carte-id'))
        {
            $image1 = $request->file('carte-id');
            if($image1->isValid())
            {
                if ($request->hasFile('avs'))
                {
                    $image2 = $request->file('avs');

                    if($image2->isValid())
                    {
                        if ($request->hasFile('permit'))
                        {
                            $image3 = $request->file('permit');

                            if($image3->isValid())
                            {
                                $path = config('card.path')."/$id";
                                $name = "carte-id.".$image1->getClientOriginalExtension();
                                $image1->move($path, $name);
                                $path = config('card.path')."/$id";
                                $name = "avs.".$image2->getClientOriginalExtension();
                                $image2->move($path, $name);
                                $path = config('card.path')."/$id";
                                $name = "permit.".$image3->getClientOriginalExtension();
                                $image3->move($path, $name);
                                $message = "Super ! Vous avez importé tous les fichiers nécessaires.";
                                //ici on dit dans la DB que l'utilisateur à uploadé tous les fichiers
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        return redirect()->route('account', $id)->with('message', $message);
    }
```

And here are the CardAvsRequest rules:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'carte-id' => 'mimes:jpg,png,pdf,gif,jpeg,tiff,doc,docx,odt|max:10000',
            'avs' => 'mimes:jpg,png,pdf,gif,jpeg,tiff,doc,docx,odt|max:10000',
            'permit' => 'mimes:jpg,png,pdf,gif,jpeg,tiff,doc,docx,odt|max:10000',
        ];
    }
```

But every time i try to upload a file (such as a video file or a executable file) that is supposed to generate a validation error, i have this laravel error :

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67
```

I just want my error to display not a laravel one.

Any ideas ?

Comment: How big are these files? Found [something simulair](http://laravel.io/forum/02-20-2014-l40-csrf-tokenmismatchexception-when-uploading-large-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token line should be

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

only two curly braces not three

Comment: Doesn't change anything... It worked with 3 curly braces

Comment: Yes it does ! @Huzaib

Comment: @baptiste-arnaud please share the code of the controller method... All of it, starting from `public function...`

Comment: I don't see any apparent errors. Your code is good. Does it work when you fill in the form well?

Comment: Did you use two curly braces instead of three?

Comment: It works when when i fill the form well. Well errors are supposed to be displayed with validation rules. i display errors in my blade template like this : @if(count($errors) > 0)
          @foreach ($errors->all() as $error){{ $error }}@endforeach

Comment: Then the only idea I believe is that the uploaded files are bigger than what your server is configured to allow as `max_upload_size`

Comment: That's the error indeed. But I don't want this to be display if someone is uploading a very large file. What should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace this:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}" />
```

with:

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

this will generate all the html for you. So it will generate this for example.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="vVGUrt0Grroh7CpmI8blFH6pLQnWQzi6WBWqpZzG">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check Your laravel installation path was same as set in the config file `session.php`.One more solution is just comment the line `'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken'`  from kernel.php under the `app\http` folder.But it's not a correct way to do.